# WebGL occasional visible borders / seams when interpolating fragment colors

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, webgl

I was playing around with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Creating_3D_objects_using_WebGL) tutorial on creating 3D objects using WebGL and changed colors so that every vertex (corner of the cube) has its own color instead of the 'default' one color per face, and that's result:

```js
var cubeRotation = 0.0;

main();

//
// Start here
//
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');

  // If we don't have a GL context, give up now

  if (!gl) {
    alert('Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it.');
    return;
  }

  // Vertex shader program

  const vsSource = `
    attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec4 aVertexColor;

    uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

    varying lowp vec4 vColor;

    void main(void) {
      gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * aVertexPosition;
      vColor = aVertexColor;
    }
  `;

  // Fragment shader program

  const fsSource = `
    varying lowp vec4 vColor;

    void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vColor;
    }
  `;

  // Initialize a shader program; this is where all the lighting
  // for the vertices and so forth is established.
  const shaderProgram = initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource);

  // Collect all the info needed to use the shader program.
  // Look up which attributes our shader program is using
  // for aVertexPosition, aVevrtexColor and also
  // look up uniform locations.
  const programInfo = {
    program: shaderProgram,
    attribLocations: {
      vertexPosition: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aVertexPosition'),
      vertexColor: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aVertexColor'),
    },
    uniformLocations: {
      projectionMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uProjectionMatrix'),
      modelViewMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uModelViewMatrix'),
    },
  };

  // Here's where we call the routine that builds all the
  // objects we'll be drawing.
  const buffers = initBuffers(gl);

  var then = 0;

  // Draw the scene repeatedly
  function render(now) {
    now *= 0.001; // convert to seconds
    const deltaTime = now - then;
    then = now;

    drawScene(gl, programInfo, buffers, deltaTime);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

//
// initBuffers
//
// Initialize the buffers we'll need. For this demo, we just
// have one object -- a simple three-dimensional cube.
//
function initBuffers(gl) {

  // Create a buffer for the cube's vertex positions.

  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  // Select the positionBuffer as the one to apply buffer
  // operations to from here out.

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  // Now create an array of positions for the cube.

  const positions = [
    // Front face
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

    // Back face
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

    // Top face
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,

    // Bottom face
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,

    // Right face
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,

    // Left face
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  ];

  // Now pass the list of positions into WebGL to build the
  // shape. We do this by creating a Float32Array from the
  // JavaScript array, then use it to fill the current buffer.

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // Now set up the colors for the faces. We'll use solid colors
  // for each face.

  const faceColors = [
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], // Front face: white
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], // Back face: red
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], // Top face: green
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], // Bottom face: blue
    [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], // Right face: yellow
    [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], // Left face: purple
  ];

  // Build the element array buffer; this specifies the indices
  // into the vertex arrays for each face's vertices.

  const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);

  // This array defines each face as two triangles, using the
  // indices into the vertex array to specify each triangle's
  // position.

  const indices = [
    0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, // front
    4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, // back
    8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11, // top
    12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15, // bottom
    16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, // right
    20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23, // left
  ];

  // Now send the element array to GL

  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  return {
    position: positionBuffer,
    indices: indexBuffer,
  };
}

//
// Draw the scene.
//
function drawScene(gl, programInfo, buffers, deltaTime) {
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // Clear to black, fully opaque
  gl.clearDepth(1.0); // Clear everything
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST); // Enable depth testing
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL); // Near things obscure far things

  // Clear the canvas before we start drawing on it.

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Create a perspective matrix, a special matrix that is
  // used to simulate the distortion of perspective in a camera.
  // Our field of view is 45 degrees, with a width/height
  // ratio that matches the display size of the canvas
  // and we only want to see objects between 0.1 units
  // and 100 units away from the camera.

  const fieldOfView = 45 * Math.PI / 180; // in radians
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const zNear = 0.1;
  const zFar = 100.0;
  const projectionMatrix = mat4.create();

  // note: glmatrix.js always has the first argument
  // as the destination to receive the result.
  mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix,
    fieldOfView,
    aspect,
    zNear,
    zFar);

  // Set the drawing position to the "identity" point, which is
  // the center of the scene.
  const modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();

  // Now move the drawing position a bit to where we want to
  // start drawing the square.

  mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix, // destination matrix
    modelViewMatrix, // matrix to translate
    [-0.0, 0.0, -6.0]); // amount to translate
  mat4.rotate(modelViewMatrix, // destination matrix
    modelViewMatrix, // matrix to rotate
    cubeRotation, // amount to rotate in radians
    [0, 0, 1]); // axis to rotate around (Z)
  mat4.rotate(modelViewMatrix, // destination matrix
    modelViewMatrix, // matrix to rotate
    cubeRotation * .7, // amount to rotate in radians
    [0, 1, 0]); // axis to rotate around (X)

  // Tell WebGL how to pull out the positions from the position
  // buffer into the vertexPosition attribute
  {
    const numComponents = 3;
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 7 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.position);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition,
      numComponents,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(
      programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition);
  }

  // Tell WebGL how to pull out the colors from the color buffer
  // into the vertexColor attribute.
  {
    const numComponents = 4;
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 7 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
    const offset = 3 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.position);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      programInfo.attribLocations.vertexColor,
      numComponents,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(
      programInfo.attribLocations.vertexColor);
  }

  // Tell WebGL which indices to use to index the vertices
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.indices);

  // Tell WebGL to use our program when drawing

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

  // Set the shader uniforms

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
    programInfo.uniformLocations.projectionMatrix,
    false,
    projectionMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
    programInfo.uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix,
    false,
    modelViewMatrix);

  {
    const vertexCount = 36;
    const type = gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, vertexCount, type, offset);
  }

  // Update the rotation for the next draw

  cubeRotation += deltaTime;
}

//
// Initialize a shader program, so WebGL knows how to draw our data
//
function initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource) {
  const vertexShader = loadShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource);
  const fragmentShader = loadShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource);

  // Create the shader program

  const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

  // If creating the shader program failed, alert

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert('Unable to initialize the shader program: ' + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
    return null;
  }

  return shaderProgram;
}

//
// creates a shader of the given type, uploads the source and
// compiles it.
//
function loadShader(gl, type, source) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(type);

  // Send the source to the shader object

  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);

  // Compile the shader program

  gl.compileShader(shader);

  // See if it compiled successfully

  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert('An error occurred compiling the shaders: ' + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    gl.deleteShader(shader);
    return null;
  }

  return shader;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
<canvas width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

On two faces triangles appear to have a seam between them (colors are not interpolated as nicely as on the rest of them), my question is why?

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate because I'm pretty sure the linked Q&A answers your question. You might find [these tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org) useful while learing webgl.

Comment: @gman Thanks a lot, I couldn't find anything on the topic so that's why I asked. Your answer on the linked question is awesome.